# Page content dissapears after loading the page

Tags: customization, errors

All my pages work fine except those that are superior pages. After clicking the name of the page in the menu and loading the page the content shows itself for like a second and then it dissapears. [Here](http://www.zanzibarcz.cz/index.php/recepty-a-techniky/).

Every other page works. I am using the Avada theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable ConvertPlug plugin, for some unknown reason, it's adding `display: none;` to your content.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.